# What is simpliest way to dispatch fault event in GraniteDS service

Tags: java, apache-flex, exception, graniteds

I am trying to dispatch fault event in GraniteDS service

method call (Flex):

```
userService.addUser(user, null, function addUserFault(e:TideFaultEvent):void {
                Alert.show(e.fault.faultString); 
            });
```

server method (Spring):

```
@Override
    public User addUser(User user) throws Exception{
        if(findUserByName(user.getUsername()) != null)
            throw new Exception("Username Already Exist");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        return user;
    }
```

But what i get is silence on client side and `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` in server console.
How can i use default graniteds exception converter to deliver fault event to client (Flex)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I dont know if it's a bug or not, but you cannot set result function to null and specify fault function only - this wont work. My call method should look like:

```
userService.addUser(user, function addUserResult(e:TideResultEvent){
                // do nothing
            }, function addUserFault(e:TideFaultEvent):void {
                Alert.show(e.fault.faultString); 
            });
```

in this case java Exception in remote method will be send back to flex as TideFaultEvent.